# ember.js observer for all values

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember.js, is there a good way of adding an observer that will observe all changes on an instance of a subclass of `Ember.Object`?

ie *(coffeescript)*

```
Bat = Ember.Object.extend
    name: null
    age: null

hank = Bat.create
    name: 'Hank'
    age: 2

#Something like this
hank.addObserverToAll myClass, 'handleChange'
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193712/how-do-i-observe-all-property-changes-on-a-model-object

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like that poor guy never got a good answer... And he asked 5 months ago. :(

Comment: @Rajat also the article that is linked in that post no longer seems to be valid or the current build of ember

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/GMwCu/

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.WatchedObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstProp: null,
  secondProp: "bar",

  init: function(){
    this._super();
    var self = this;
    Ember.keys(this).forEach(function(key){
      if(Ember.typeOf(self.get(key)) !== 'function'){
        self.addObserver(key, function(){
          console.log(self.get(key));
        });
      }
    }); 
  }
});

App.watched = App.WatchedObject.create({
  firstProp:"foo",
  plop: function(){},
  thirdProp: 'far'
});

App.watched.set('firstProp', 'trigObserver');
App.watched.set('secondProp', 'doesNotTrigObserver');
App.watched.set('thirdProp', 'alsoTrigObserver');
```

​

As you can see, it handles only properties, not functions (I think it's what's you want).
You can also realize that it works only for properties passed to `create()` method, not those specified in the class definition (ie using `extend`).

Comment: Thanks man, was hoping Ember handled it natively, but this is an elegant solution!

Comment: N.B. It only observes properties passed at the `create` method. Not those specified in the class definition (using `extend`).

Comment: Yep, that's what I said in my comment below the code, but it seems not clear, I update. Thanks @louiscoquio