# Does Ember 1.0 prerelease support property changed?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my application, I get json objects from server then convert to Ember.Object and binding to html control. Users will be change some of field and submit to server. But I just only want to submit fields which has changed by user.

My pseude code:

```
var jsObj = myObj.getProperties(myObj.getListPropertyChanged);
```

Then, I convert jsObj to json and sent to server.

Does Ember.js prerelease support that?.

Currenty, I inject my code into Ember.Set function to track property changed, it's work but I really don't want do that.

I am looking new solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mixin for this sort functionality.

[Ember.Mixin](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Mixin&src=false)

[Ember.Editable](https://gist.github.com/3294879)

Comment: Ember.Mixin can't apply for my goal. It's difference situation.
This is one solution but it's not good:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193712/how-do-i-observe-all-property-changes-on-a-model-object

Comment: Take a look at this [Ember.Editable](https://gist.github.com/3294879) mixin, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Ember.Editable is suitable with my requirement. This is demo with your suggest http://jsfiddle.net/sangcu/feCYT/1/. It's working. I also hope Ember team will support this function in Ember library for clear code and more simple

Comment: I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feCYT/2/) so it uses ember-1.0.pre.js. Now you can get the changed properties like this: App.model.get('dirtyProps')