# Observe properties on nested object

Tags: ember.js

Example fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aviyUnA/9/edit?html,js,output

This is my model:

```
{
  name: {
    title: 'Mr',
    first: 'Potato',
    last:  'Head'
  },

  age: 79
}
```

How do I create a computed property that observes all the keys inside the `name` object without listing them manually?

```
fullName: function() {
  var name = this.get('name');
  return [name.title, name.first, name.last].join(' ');
}.property('name.??')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would have to list them all in that case. See [this question also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193712/how-do-i-observe-all-property-changes-on-a-model-object).

Comment: I was worried about that. In this case it's not that big of a deal but definitely something to keep in mind. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the `set` call of your model: Check if the value being set involves a property of `name` and if it does, call `notifyPropertyChange` on `name`:

```
App.MyModel = Ember.Object.extend({
   set: function(keyName, value) {
     this._super(keyName, value);
     if (keyName.indexOf('name.') > -1) {
       // a property of `name` has changed => notify observers of `name`
       this.notifyPropertyChange('name');
     }
   }
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/akEjubU/1/edit