# EmberJS pushobject on an object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to setup a property on an object that will be an object, like this.

Say I have the property called cities, and I want to have a value of population, on a normal object I would do

```
cities: {
  'city1': 100,
  'city2': 200
}
```

now if I want to add city3 i could do

```
this.get('cities')['city3'] = 300
```

while this will update the object it won't propagate the bindings, I could make it an array and just use `pushObject`, but I would rather have it so that if inputing info about a particular city, if it already exists, it just updates the old data.

So is there a way to have that and being observable?

Thanks

Edit even using the

> this.set('cities.city1',100)

won't notify on changes as I can observe @each, I used the trick on this answer to get it to work.

[Observe properties on nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245792/observe-properties-on-nested-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `=` will not trigger any of the observers and bindings, you need to use `set` example:

```
this.set('cities.city3', 300);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `set` instead of `=`.

```
this.set('cities.city3', 300);
```

Comment: it's still not propagating, it does update as I want it to, but when I observe 'cities.@each' or just 'cities' it doesn't fire on update

Comment: `@each` watches items on a collection, and watching `cities` wouldn't fire any change since the cities reference itself hasn't changed.