# How to check for dirty changes made to a object in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I have a object when any of the value to the keys inside the object changes I want to update a computed property. Is there a way to observe the value changes of an object with computed property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I observe \*all\* property changes on a model object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193712/how-do-i-observe-all-property-changes-on-a-model-object)

Comment: If the object is of type `DS.Model`, then `isDirty` is your friend (this will watch only model properties, not your own computed properties). If the object is of some other type, there is no easy way. See the question suggested as a duplicate.

Comment: its not of type DS.Model; 
I guess I have to observe each and every propery of the object seperately

Comment: Then maybe yes, but the question suggested as a duplicate has some other ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Computed properties and observers are two different things. Computed properties automatically "observe" specified properties and recompute themselves lazily when needed. Observers are used less frequently when you want to perform some action immediately when a property changes. In your case, you seem to want something like this in your model. If it is indeed a `DS.Model` as it appears to be, then you can use `isDirty`. If you'd prefer to put this in the controller, use `model.isDirty` (or in most recent versions of Ember Data `model.hasDirtyAttributes`) instead:

```
updateServer: function() {
  if (!this.get('isDirty')) return;
  pingServer();
}.observes('isDirty')
```

If you want to have a computed property which is recomputed whenever any of the model properties change, you can list `isDirty` as a dependency. This is an example of a controller property:

```
canSave: function() {
  return this.get('isEditing') && this.get('model.isDirty');
}.property('isEditing', 'model.isDirty')
```

and then, for example

```
<button class="{{if canSave 'active'}}">Save</button>
```

The button will be automatically made active (via the `active` CSS class) whenever the user is in editing mode and the model is dirty.

The `isDirty` flag is cleared when the model is saved. If you are not saving the model, but want to clear the `isDirty` flag, you can do

If you want to observe all property changes on a non-`DS.Model` object, or observe changes to your own defined properties on the model (as opposed to `DS.*` type properties), then this is a hard problem to solve. Ember provides no out-of-the-box solution. You can Google for "observe changes to Ember object properties", or review the question proposed as a duplicate.

Comment: to observer each attribute of an object i have to observe like 

.observers(object.attributeA,object.attributeB,object.attributeC) and so on

so i what i wanted is to know a short hand for observing all properties of an object smehow like this

.observers(object)

instead of specifying each attribute

Comment: Why does `isDirty` not work for doing what you want?

Comment: object not of type DS.Model

Comment: hasDirtyAttributes does not work for async properties ( belongsTo) .  Any1 has a good solution for this ?

Comment: There is `hasDirtyRelationships` (in the future). Meanwhile, you'll have to handle that yourself, by watching `isDirty` on the associated models and updating it on the main model.

Comment: @Neovire The title of your question is "How to check for dirty changes made to a **model** in ember js". If you're not dealing with a model, please change the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can define computed properties in your model like so :

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:     DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:      DS.attr('string')

    /* COMPUTED */
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

You can now use your new `fullName` property and it will be magically updated whenever the `firstName` or `lastName` changes.

**UPDATE**

In order to poke your server when something changes, you could do something like that in your ObjectController:

```
changesObserver: function() {
    // this will be called everytime one of the attribute is changed
    // so you could do your server post here I guess
    Ember.$.ajax(/*...*/);
}.observes('attributeA', 'attributeB', etc)
```

Comment: I want to observe an object data changes in a computed property

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve... could you provide me an example ?

Comment: I have a form that is already filled and when any one of the value changes in the form changes I want to notify the server that the form has been updated.

all fields in the form are as key:value pair is inside model object

Comment: to observer each attribute of an object i have to observe like 

.observers(object.attributeA,object.attributeB,object.attributeC) and so on

so i what i wanted is to know a short hand for observing all properties of an object smehow like this

.observers(object)

instead of specifying each attribute

Comment: you can subscribe your observers with a loop : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388402/how-to-observe-all-object-property-changes

Comment: it wld have been great if ember had atleast two level observers this kinda makes code complicated

Comment: personnally, i prefer to specify each attributes, it may be a bit redundant, but it makes it more evident to see "which" attribute triggers the observer.

Comment: consider the form gets bigger (around 15 fields) or the form changes depending on whether the user wants a field or not.
so i will have unnecessary properties that is observed and also as the form fields increases, we have to keep on adding to the observer list makes the code look kinda odd.

Comment: well, I think that "automagic" stuff looks odd but it personnal taste. Either way, you can user the look I linked you before to observes everything you need on the fly. Both solutions are there, and I don't think for any other alternatives by now.